# Is there a way to change the datatype for a column without changing the order of the column?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a column where I want to change the data type. I currently am using Redshift. I know I can use the alter table statement to change the datatype, but this would change the order of the columns.

Is there a way to change the datatype without changing the order of the column?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a new table with the schema you want and copying it over from the old table using a `insert into new_table (select * from old_table)` statement (here you can also do any casting to the new data type), after which you can drop the old table and rename the new one:

```
drop table old_table;
alter table new_table rename to old_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type` will not change the order of the columns in your table.

Please note that this clause can only changes the size of a column defined as a VARCHAR data type.
There are also other limitations described in [AWS documentation of ALTER TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html)